# How to repeat HTML table header (thead) for each page rendersAs pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, html

I would like to as you how to repeat table header ( thead) for each page on the top ??
the simple code is like this :

```html
</messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
    <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" filename="{!relatedTo.Name}.pdf">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Head 1</th>
                           <th>Head 2</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td>value 1</td>
                           <td>value 2 </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>value 3</td>
                           <td>value 4</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

so according this example , I would like to reapeat ( Head 1 and Head 2) at the beginning of each page .
I test this code but it doesn't work :

```css
@page {
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
}
```

I tested `thead {display: table-header-group;}`but it doesn't work

an idea ??

thanks

Answer (score 11):

Inside your CSS in tables style tag, you need to add the following attribute:

```
table {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
```

puts a header at the start of each new page where a table crosses a page boundary.

The `-fs` reportedly refers to Flying Saucer, the render engine used by SF to create PDFs and is specific to that render engine (not for use elsewhere).

Comment: Yes, Flying Saucer is indeed used by SF to create the PDFs. I don't remember where I read this, but I've had to look at the FS manual on more than one occasion to get some obscure CSS trick to work just right.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code its help you

```css
thead, tfoot {
    display: table-row-group
}
```