# apex:dataTable render as pdf headers

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have an apex:dataTable on a Visualforce page that is rendered as pdf. What I am after is having the table headers on top of each page when data is large enough to be over multiple page. Is this doable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat HTML table header (thead) for each page rendersAs pdf](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83042/how-to-repeat-html-table-header-thead-for-each-page-rendersas-pdf)