# How to set the size of a column table unchanged on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, html

the text overflows from the column while I set the width of the column

```
 <apex:repeat var="cases" value="{!Quote.QuoteLineItems}">
       <tr width="100%">
       <td  style="border-right:2px solid black;" width="10%">{!cases.Product2.ProductCode}
           </td>
           <td style="border-right:2px solid black" align="left" width="50%">
               
               <b>{!cases.Product2.Name}</b><br/>{!cases.Product2.Description} 
           </td>
            <td style="border-right:2px solid black;" width="10%">{!cases.Quantity}
           </td>
            <td style="border-right:2px solid black;" width="10%">{!cases.ListPrice}
           </td>
            <td style="border-right:2px solid black;" width="10%">{!cases.Discount}
           </td>
            <td style="border-right:2px solid black;"  width="10%">{!cases.TotalPrice}
           </td>
           
       </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
```

I Get This:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding auto-hyphenation:

```
<td style="hyphens: auto; border-right:2px solid black" align="left" width="50%">
```

Or, you can truncate the text:

```
<td style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; border-right:2px solid black" align="left" width="50%">
```

If you use the Salesforce Lightning Design System, it includes patterns for doing this automatically with [slds-truncate](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/truncation/).

Just add `<apex:slds/>` to your page, and set a scope for SLDS with `<div class="slds-scope">` near the top of your page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
when I use this: <td style = "overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; border-right: 2px solid black" align = "left" width = "50%">
it works for the first line but the other lines part of the designation is no longer displayed

Comment: @maya You can try auto-hyphenation as an alternative, or just make sure that no word exceeds a number of characters. Your use case is rather contrived; most legitimate data shouldn't flow over into the next cell.

Comment: thank you so much!
sorry i know i ask too much! i need help displaying my table header on the second page if the table page breaks.?

Comment: @maya no worries, check [this out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/83042/2984). Should be exactly what you need.

Comment: thank you very much that works!
Is there a way to translate the product description on the visualforce page?

Comment: The description field is a text value, so you'd have to call some sort of translation service in the controller.

Comment: need help with css in visualforce page  rendered as pdf border radius not working !

Comment: @maya I'd be glad to help you, however, this question is not the place to do so. Please ask a new question and provide sufficient code for us to help you, and we'll be glad to do so.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not on purpose but I can't ask questions it seems that I was blocked!!

Comment: this is the link of my question: https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3049/72453